# Speed up anagram method in Ruby

Tags: optimization, performance, algorithm, ruby

I'm working on a project to find anagrams of words. My goal is to figure out the longest anagrams out there. I took a look at my code and it works but is woefully inefficient.

I have two arrays, each containing a length of long words:

```
words_one = ["sarcocarcinomata", "dactylopteridae", "autoradiographic", "pterylographical",
"nonconversational", "pathophysiological"]

words_two = ["carcinosarcomata", "pterodactylidae", "radioautographic", "pterylographical", "nonconservational", "physiopathological"]
```

Most of these words have to do with science, so they're relatively long.

For what I'm working on, I would like to find if all of the word pairs are anagrams of each other. In my example above, they are.

```
def anagrams(words_one, words_two)
  x = 0
  while x < words_one.count
    if words_one[x].chars.to_a.permutation.include?(words_two[x].chars.to_a)
      puts 1
      x += 1
    else
      puts 0
      x += 1
    end
  end
end
```

There are several potential problems I see here:

1. **Permutation Method**: This sorts through all permutations of a given string. Each letter can be one of 26 different characters. This adds up real quickly.
2. **While Loop**: I'm not sure this is the most effective method.
3. **Duplicate Code**: I put x+=1 in both sections of my if-else block.

I'd like to learn some new techniques to optimize Ruby code.

Which type of algorithm is my code and which type of algorithm do I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the formulation *Does any permutation of word A's letters match word B?* is technically correct, it's also terribly impractical when implemented. As you yourself point out, there are *a lot* of permutations, and we're looking for just one.

A simpler formulation would be

> Are the letters in word A the same as in word B?

Or, in code

```
word_a.chars.sort == word_b.chars.sort
```

That'll be a lot quicker.

Also, since you've got 2 arrays, and want to match one word from each at a time, you could use `Array#zip` to produce a single array of pairs, and loop that instead. You rarely need to deal with plain C-style loops or actual array indexes in Ruby, because you have all the methods from `Enumerable`. It's not that these are necessarily more efficient than old-school loops, it's that they are more expressive and much more idiomatic.

One of those `Enumerable` methods, by the way, is `all?` which simply checks if a block evaluates to non-false/non-nil for all items.

So for instance, you could do this:

```
def all_anagrams?(words_one, words_two)
  words_one.zip(words_two).all? do |word_a, word_b|
    word_a.chars.sort == word_b.chars.sort
  end
end
```

Basically: pair up the words from each array, and check if the words in each and every pair are anagrams of each other.

And yes, it returns `true` for the two arrays in your question.

Of course, it doesn't say much about what words (if any) *aren't* anagrams. If you want more feedback, you could look into using `#detect` to find the first pair that isn't anagrammatic (if no such pair is found, well, they *are* all anagrams). Or you could use `#partition` to divide the list of pairs into two lists: Those that are anagrammatic, and those that are not.

In any case, I'd recommend against printing anything in a method, unless it's stated purpose is indeed to print stuff. Much better to have more methods and combine their functionality, than have a few methods do many things.

Speaking of methods, the current name of your method, `anagrams`, doesn't quite say what it does. Does it return some random anagrams? Does it produce them based on input? Does it verify them? Typically, when a method just returns a boolean value, its name is suffixed with a `?` in Ruby. Makes it nice and obvious that you can expect a yes/no answer.
I've tried for a slightly more descriptive name above with the `all_anagrams?` name (it isn't perfect either, though).

Oh, and yes, the duplication of `x += 1` is problematic. You can just move it to appear after the `if..else`. It's doubly wise to do so here, since you'll have an infinite loop if `x` doesn't get incremented as expected. So it's better to at least have the increment happen in only 1 place, than to hope it happens in several, branching code paths.